# How can i check for "-infinity" in javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to check if this numbers array is empty because when i run this code it returns `-infinity` ,so i want to checl if its empty and if so push a default value into the array and then check for max.

```js
var numbers = []; 
console.log(_.max(numbers,function(o){
    return o.id;
}));
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js" > 
</script>
```

Comment: like so?: `if (! numbers.length > 0) { nimbers.push(1) } `

Comment: `val === -Infinity`? Positive/negative infinity is just another "number" in JavaScript, so you can use strict equality like any other number.

Comment: You can also use `Number.isFinite()` to check for positive and negative `Infinity`

Comment: @PatricNox `console.log(_.max(numbers,function(o){
       if (! numbers.length > 0) { numbers.push(1); } else{return o.id;}})); `this didnt work

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check if its empty and if so push a default value into the array and then check for max

Just check whether the length is zero and push your default value in beforehand:

```js
var numbers = []; 
if(numbers.length == 0)
  numbers.push({id:0}); // or whatever default you want
console.log(_.max(numbers,function(o){
    return o.id;
}));
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js" > 
</script>
```

Comment: what if i want the if statement inside the function

Comment: @AkashVasu That doesnt make sense, the function will not be called if the array is empty

Comment: ohh in my actual code for some reason the number is initiated everytime, i thought if its inside the function it wont

Answer (score 1):

This is because _.max function returns -Infinity when the array is empty.So you can check by using `isEmpty() or simply numbers.length > 0 && _.max(numbers)`.

if you want to push the default value then do the below:

```
!numbers.length && numbers.push(defaultValue);
 _.max(numbers)
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://underscorejs.org/#max)

Comment: Didn't you mean `!numbers.length && numbers.push(defaultValue); _.max(numbers)`?

Comment: @Julian yes correct.There should not be an && clause there.Sorry my bad. Changed it